# Redirect a single file using IIS

Tags: iis, redirect

I'd like to redirect some of the large (zip) files on our server to a hosting service. I've seen some questions about HTTP redirection but they seem to always apply to the entire domain or to a folder.

I'd prefer to pick the files to redirect instead of redirecting an entire folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended it finding it on my own. It was easy after I found the "Switch to Feature View" context menu in IIS Manager.

1. If you don't have HTTP Redirection installed you'll have to install it. From the Control Panel select "Turn Windows Features on or off", then browse to `Internet Information Services` > `World Wide Web Services` > `Common HTTP Features` and select `HTTP Redirection`;
2. Boot up IIS Manager (`inetmgr.exe`);
3. Browse for your file (you may have to change to Content View to see it);
4. Right-click the file and select "Switch to Feature View". The file now appears in the Connections tree.
5. Select the file in the Connections tree, then double-click "HTTP Redirect";
6. Select "Redirect requests to this destination" and enter the address to redirect to.

Comment: This part is totally unintuitive: "Right-click the file and .. Switch to Feature View".  Thanks, because I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

[does this help](http://web.archive.org/web/20121206080205/http://strivinglife.com:80/words/post/Is-it-really-that-simple-redirecting-a-single-file-on-IIS.aspx)?

if I understand correctly, you are trying to set up a 301 Redirect for a single file?

Comment: it is useful but I think it is for IIS 6, I'm using IIS 7.